# Chained enumerable methods with enumerable itself as argument

Tags: ruby, enumeration, chaining

I have an enumerable with several chained methods. I have created a helper method which takes an enumerable and filters out results. The function requires the entire enumerable as its argument instead of being called repeatedly with each element. To illustrate what I am trying to accomplish, please reference the following:

```
[1,2,3]
.filter { |e| ... }
.map { |e| ... }
.??? { |full_enumerable_as_arg_here| my_filter_function(full_enumerable_as_arg_here) }
.sum
```

Where ??? would be a chainable method I am not sure exists in Ruby and full_enumerable_as_arg_here representing that I need it to pass the full enumerable generated by .map as opposed to each individual element. I am a ruby novice so please forgive my ignorance, but does something like this exist?

Comment: That doesn’t make a lot of sense—“map” returns an array, so you’d want a method on array or an extension etc. There’s always “tap”-like methods, too. What’s the purpose here? Why does it all need to be in one chain?

Comment: @DaveNewton I suppose it doesn't have to be, it's just the existing code was a big chain of methods and I added this filter. I need my filter to go in the middle of the chain that already exists. I was hoping there was an easy way to do this just so i didn't have to break the chain and assign to a variable, pass to my function and then start up the latter part of the chain.

Comment: It looks like "tap" may be able to do what I am looking for, though. I will give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: @arrwags I think you are actually looking for [`Kernel#yield_self`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#method-i-yield_self) aliased as [`#then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#method-i-then). The difference between `yield_self` and `tap` is that `tap` works by passing the caller to the block and returning the caller, whereas `yield_self` passes the caller to the block and returns the result of the block, so unless `my_filter_function` actually modifies `full_enumerable_as_arg_here` `tap` will simply return the same result returned by `map`